# How to identify a date for the row of each days?

Tags: arrays, perl, date, days

Please, have  a look!

I have number of days from  1 to 30 days, so I need to loop through number of days and identify a date for each correspondings days with one "for" loop, The started date is: $epoc = 2020-05-11; So, iam converting it into epoc seconds, and I found the last date in sec (30th day).I was able to solve it like this, but I need with one "for" loop. Is it possible?

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use Time::Local;
   use Time::Localtime;
   $day_a1 = 1;
   $day_a2 = 30;
   my ($year, $month, $day) = split('-', $epoc);
    $epoc = timelocal($s, $m, $h, $day, $month-1, $year-1900);
    $interval=$day_a2*60*60*24;
    $epoc1=$epoc+$interval;
    print scalar(localtime($epoc1)), "\n";

    @x1=(); 
    @date1=(); 
    for ($d = $day_a1; $d <= $day_a2; $d++){
            push (@x1, $d);
        }
    for ($d = $epoc; $d <= $epoc1; $d+=86400){
    print scalar(localtime($d));
    push (@date1, $d);
    }
    print @x1;
    print @date1;
```

Comment: Where is `timelocal` coming from?

Comment: You mean a module? just edited

Comment: Please add `use strict; use warnings` to see how many issues you have with your script.

On line #6 you use `$epoc` which is not initialized. What do you expect to see in variables?

Comment: Thank you for your help, dear @PolarBear.  Just some variables were initialized and values taken from a batch file which I used , forgot to mention in the code sorry

Answer (score 4):

You would make your life a lot easier if you used the tools that are available for you. In particular, [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) have been part of the standard Perl distribution since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $start = '2020-05-11';

# Add time of midday to avoid DST problems.
my $curr = Time::Piece->strptime("$start 12:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

for (1 .. 30) {
  say $curr->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
  $curr += ONE_DAY;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you intended to write code in following form

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Local;
use Time::Localtime;

my $days = 30;
my $date = '2020-05-11';
my $day_sec = 60*60*24;
my ($year, $month, $day) = split('-', $date);
my $epoch = timelocal(0, 0, 0, $day, $month-1, $year-1900);

for(my $day=0; $day<$days; $day++) {
    say scalar localtime($epoch);
    $epoch += $day_sec;
}
```